# How To Prove That $\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{3n} = 1$ for all n natural number is a wrong statement?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find whether the following equation is true for all values $n$ given that $n$ is a natural positive number :

$$\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{3n}= 1$$

I rewrote this to the following using Moover Rule

$$ e^{3ni\pi/3} = 1 $$

And then

$$ arg(e^{3ni\pi/3}) = arg(1)$$
The threes cancels out and I get :

$$ n\pi + 2k\pi = 0 + 2k\pi $$

Thus this is true for $ n = 0$ only and the statement is false , however while playing with wolfram alpha, I've found that this is true only if n is an even number .

Which proof is more correct ?  And why ? Is my proof wrong ?

Comment: Try $n=1$? It's not true when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Moivre not moover lol

Comment: The two $k$'s in your equation don't refer to the same variable, so you've confused yourself there. (and there are some additional subtleties involved in trying to write an equation between multivalued functions)

Comment: Would be true for $\left(\frac{-1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{3n}$ or $\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{6n}$

Comment: $$\left(e^{\pi i/3}\right)^{3n} = \left(e^{\pi i }\right)^n = (-1)^n \neq 1.$$

Comment: His name was DE MOIVRE, not Moover. Your proof is correct. Not more correct or less correct. Nothing wrong with it, and well-written,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $ e^{3ni\pi/3} = 1 $. That is

$$1=(e^{i\pi})^n=(-1)^n$$

The equality holds if and only if $n$ is even.

---

$ e^{3ni\pi/3} = 1 $ implies that $\arg(e^{in\pi})$ and $\arg(1)$ have the same principal values. So $n\pi $ and $0$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$. $n$ has to be even.